# How to refill the form by fetching data from mysql in php

Tags: php, image

Here is a situation,in which there are two page one for uploading image and other for displaying the image. on uploading image ,a choose file button is there and on display page ,the uploading image will be shown and a button is also for redirect to the first page ,now i want that when user click on display page (redirect button) then uploaded image in the database will automatically refill in the first page (choose file button).I am trying to feteh the image name and refill in the choose file button but the choose file button shows "No File Selected",how to do that

Comment: Please share relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'pre-populate' a FILE input value. (Its a browser security risk)

Answer (score 0):

Its a good practice, to replace file upload inputs with image, and put there delete button. After that, show new, empty file input.

You cant use server path on file input.

Answer (score 0):

Browser's prevent you from doing this, so that files cannot be uploaded without the users interaction.